# MVC 5 Custom Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a custom UserStoreManager and I add same custom field into ApplicationUser.

It's work fine.

Now, I have a question. How I can get the ApplicationUser custom field value from a Controller?

I find the UserId information calling User.identity.getuserid or User.identity.getuserName but how I can access to the ApplicationUser Field?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get **ApplicationUser** first for the current user.

```
var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());
var customField = currentUser.CustomField;

private AppUserManager UserManager
{
   get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>(); }
}
```

Comment: but I do it every time?

Comment: Yes, Identity doesn't know the custom property name, so you cannot retrieve it like `GetXXX`.

Answer (score 1):

You just pull the user from the database. Something like:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```